# ‬‎ <column name> ‪is‬‎ ‪not‬‎ ‪valid‬‎ ‪in‬‎ ‪the‬‎ ‪context‬‎ ‪where‬‎ ‪it‬‎ ‪is‬‎ ‪used‬‎.‪‬‎

Tags: db2

I've been at this Create Trigger for a while...

I'm using IBM Data Studio 4.1.3 while making this Trigger. At first I had problems with ending statements with ';' but on the IBM website it says to use 'x' and it works.

My main problem, however, wondering why I get this message:

```
‬‪‬‎"‪N.ITEMNAME"‬‎ ‪is‬‎ ‪not‬‎ ‪valid‬‎ ‪in‬‎ ‪the‬‎ ‪context‬‎ ‪where‬‎ ‪it‬‎ ‪is‬‎ ‪used‬‎.‪‬‎.‪‬‎ ‪SQLCODE‬‎=‪‬‎-‪206‬‎,‪‬‎ ‪SQLSTATE‬‎=‪42703‬‎,‪‬‎ ‪DRIVER‬‎=‪3‬‎.‪69‬‎.‪56
```

This also applies to all the others: o.itemid, o.quantity, and n.quantity. I found this out when switching/swapping the names around each other.

The editor is telling me that it has no errors in the statement but when executing, problems arise.

```
-- <ScriptOptions statementTerminator="x" />
CREATE TRIGGER DB2ADMIN.SUPPLIES_I
AFTER UPDATE OF QUANTITY ON DB2ADMIN.SUPPLIES
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS n 
            OLD TABLE AS o 
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL NOT SECURED
BEGIN ATOMIC
    INSERT INTO db2admin.tran_log VALUES (USER, CURRENT TIMESTAMP || ' ' || n.itemname || ' ( ' || o.itemid || ' ) from ' || CHAR(o.quantity) || ' to ' || CHAR(n.quantity));
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `TABLE` word from the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DB2ADMIN.SUPPLIES_I
AFTER UPDATE OF QUANTITY ON DB2ADMIN.SUPPLIES
REFERENCING NEW AS n 
            OLD AS o 
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL NOT SECURED
BEGIN ATOMIC
    INSERT INTO db2admin.tran_log VALUES (USER, CURRENT TIMESTAMP || ' ' || n.itemname || ' ( ' || o.itemid || ' ) from ' || CHAR(o.quantity) || ' to ' || CHAR(n.quantity));
END
```

You can't reference a table transition variable in the way you try. Imagine, that we build the `new` table as below.

It's possible:

```
with n(i) as (values 1, 2, 3)
select i 
from n;
```

It's not possible, and you get the same error message:

```
with n(i) as (values 1, 2, 3)
values (n.i);
```

### Alternative solution with a `FOR EACH STATEMENT` trigger

If you your table have a key (one or more columns), and it doesn't include the updated column `QUANTITY`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DB2ADMIN.SUPPLIES_I2
AFTER UPDATE OF QUANTITY ON DB2ADMIN.SUPPLIES
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS n 
            OLD TABLE AS o 
FOR EACH STATEMENT
INSERT INTO db2admin.tran_log 
SELECT USER, CURRENT TIMESTAMP || ' ' || n.itemname || ' ( ' || o.itemid || ' ) from ' || CHAR(o.quantity) || ' to ' || CHAR(n.quantity)
FROM n, o
WHERE n.<key>=o.<key>
```

Comment: It works, thank you for that! Can I ask why taking out TABLE would work? It makes sense to reference an entire table to an alias.

Comment: @Xiaofan Some explanation added.

Comment: For the alternative solution, from what I understand, the table gets a primary key column that is auto-incremented when it is not specified. Also, you used a subquery getting data from table 'supplies' to insert into table 'tran_log'?

Comment: @Xiaofan As far as I understood from your initial example, the logic of this trigger is to insert some row into `tran_log` with an expression containing both new and old value for each updated row in `SUPPLIES`. This can be done with 2 different triggers. One of them fires as many times as a number of rows were updated in `SUPPLIES`, and inserts 1 row per invocation (`for each row` trigger). Another one (`for each statement`) fires 1 time disregarding the number of updated rows and insert the same number of rows as the 1-st one, but using 1 insert statement.